# Do I have to use different image sizes on android apps or is there a way to change the image resolution?

Tags: java, resolution

Do I have to use 5 different image sizes on android apps or is there any other way to change the resolution of the Image using a bitmap or something else?

I'm currently copying it to 5 different sizes but it seems there should be a better way to do this programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

It's best to load a smaller resource for a smaller screen density and a larger resource for larger density due to how much memory a larger bitmap has to allocate.

Although sometimes you need a bitmap to scale to a certain size to manage several screen sizes, where you call

```
Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap src, int dstWidth, int dstHeight, boolean filter)
```

Another way is that if you are drawing a bitmap onDraw(), you can use the drawBitmap() method by passing a destination Rect/RectF where the image will automatically fill.